# HDMI switches - how are they supposed to work?

Tags: hdmi, switch

I have never used any HDMI switch before, so my knowledge about them is zero.
Now I have one and I am wondering if its behaviour is normal.
I have a beamer for the output signal, a Wii U as first input signal and a laptop as second input signal. The switch I bought has one output and two input plugs, so I put them in accordingly. The packaging says that the switch has an automatic switching function, pretending that the correct signal will be recognized.

Now what happens? The switch only let a signal through if BOTH input devices are PLUGGED IN AND SWITCHED ON. Then, I can use the manual switch button to switch to the signal I want. But whenever I turn one of the devices off (Wii U or laptop) or unplug it (we only plug the laptop in if we want to wantch movies), no signal gets through to the beamer. And the manual switch button does not work either.

Is this behaviour normal, or have I just bought junk?
I was expecting that it recognizes if just one input is switched on and lets this signal through accordingly. This is what I think of "automatic switching".

What are your experiences with HDMI switches? Are there any models that do what I expect of them, or is the behaviour of my switch the normal one? Mine is from Vivanco, and it cost 45€. It says "full HDTV" and 1080p, and supports deep color.

Any suggestions on other manufacturers, models and usual prices will be appreciated. I live in Germany, so if anyone knows models I can get here (via amazon.de or just some media store), this will be especially appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Most video switches will attempt to draw power from the inputs, but if you want them to work in all conditions (e.g., no input providing power to one side) you need a separate power connection.  Your switch probably has a DC power input: just get a corresponding connector and plug it in.